# Consigo colocar o pyautogui para copiar textos de um .txt?

Tags: python, instagram-api, pyautogui

Estou com o projeto de fazer um comentador de publicações do Instagram, pra uso próprio, mas não sei como fazer o pyautogui pegar uma linha (De um arquivo .txt) ou seja um @ (Ex: @Joaozinho) e escrever, depois para o proximo @ (Ex: @Joaozinho *ENTER* @maria *ENTER* @pedro [...]) o codigo que fiz foi isso:

````
import pyautogui
import random

time.sleep(6)
pyautogui.write('Oi')
pyautogui.hotkey('return')
time.sleep(6)```

alguem me ajuda?
````

Answer (score 0):

Podes ler ficheiros de texto diretamente com o python. Aqui está um exemplo:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    time.sleep(6)
    pyautogui.write(line)
    pyautogui.hotkey('return')
    time.sleep(6)
```